# Change the navbar color in MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, materialize

I want to dynamically change the background color of the navbar from Materialize, so it needs to be done via a CSS. 
I tried doing

```
.nav-wrapper{
 background-color: <MYCOLOR HERE> !important;
}
```

But it just stays the same colored as mentioned in the class of the navbar.

Comment: Could you also include the HTML?  I imagine you probably have a color class like `class="teal darken-1"` on the element or something like that that has a higher specificity than your rule here.  It might be easily resolvable by just changing your selector to `div.nav-wrapper` or similar.

Answer (score 17):

Because in Materialize you have to change `nav`'s background-color, for example you want white navbar:

```
.nav {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Another solution, to add `<nav>`'s class `white`:

```
<nav class="white">
```

It'll change navbar's backgroud-color too.

If you're using sass or scss, you have one more solution:

```
nav {
  @extend .white;
}
```

Hope, it helps you!

Comment: white background with white text too? serious?

Answer (score 0):

For class **nav-wrapper** use:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    background-color: #850000 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the color name and light/darkness as a class to the element. See details at [Color-Matrialize](https://materializecss.com/color.html).

Comment: May you send some example, please?

Answer (score -4):

**Use Jquery to change color of navbar dynamically**

> ```
>   $(".nav-wrapper").css("background-color", themeColor);
> ```

**Here is my code Snippet**

```
 </body>

<script>

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("themeColor", "blue");
    // Retrieve
    $("#themeColor").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("themeColor");
} else {
    $("#themeColor").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

      $(".nav-wrapper").css("background-color", 'purple');
      $(".secondary-content>.material-icons").css("color", 'purple');
      $(".btn").css("background-color", 'purple');
      $(".page-footer").css("background-color", 'purple');
      $(".input-field").css("color", 'purple');
      $(".input-field>.material-icons").css("color", 'purple');
      $(".input-field>label").css("color", 'purple');

function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
       color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   }
   return color;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
      var themeColor = getRandomColor();
      $(".nav-wrapper").css("background-color", themeColor);
      $(".secondary-content>.material-icons").css("color", themeColor);
      $(".btn").css("background-color", themeColor);
      $(".page-footer").css("background-color", themeColor);
      $(".input-field").css("color", themeColor);
      $(".input-field>.material-icons").css("color", themeColor);
      $(".input-field>label").css("color", themeColor);
      $(".btn-floating").css("background-color", themeColor);

    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

**See the Live Demo Here**

See the Pen [Materialize CSS Change Theme Color](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/EXoPRq/) by Hitesh  Sahu ([@hiteshsahu](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).